# Django annotate using WHEN CASE

Tags: python, django

I have a question regarding annotation in Django, and inside the annotation I have  CASE WHEN conditions, same as in the following example:

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(
                title=Case(When(title_filter, then=Value("any text")),
                                  When(test_filter, then=F('name')),
                                  When(test1_filter, then=F('test__name')),
                                  output_field=CharField()),
                key=Case(When(title_filter, then=F('category__id')),
                                When(test_filter, then=F('test_id')),
                                When(test1_filter, then=F('test1__id')),
                                output_field=CharField()))
```

I want to annotate these fileds, title, key. But, we can see that for the each field is applyed the same condition, like Case(When(title_filter), When(category_filter)).
There is a posiblity to apply the condintion just once and after that to apply the value for each field ?
Like:

```
if title_filter:
  title = Value("any text")
  key =then=F('category__id')
elif test_filter:
 title = F('name')
 key = F('test_id')
```